# Trying to draw on a UIView with UIPanGesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```
class theView: UIView
{
 var kl = 1
    var px : CGFloat = 0.0
    var py : CGFloat = 0.0

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        color()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }


        func move(gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer)
            {
            let state = gesture.state
            switch state
            {
            case .Began: print("started")
            case .Ended: fallthrough
            case .Changed:
                let translation = gesture.translationInView(self)
                px = translation.x
                py = translation.y
                print("x:\(px), y:\(py)")
            default: break
            }
        }
        func color()
        {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.moveToPoint(CGPointZero)
            path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: px, y: py))
            UIColor.blueColor().set()
            path.stroke()
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
}
```

This is the code i have in my view. What am i missing and it doesn't show up on my screen?it does recognise my movement since `px` and `py` change values.This is part of bigger project so tell me if there are any compilling errors..

my viewController is :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, Moveable
{
    var k = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var sdasd: theView!
        {
            didSet
            {
                    sdasd.k = self
                    sdasd.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
                    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: sdasd, action: "move:")
                    sdasd.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
                    sdasd.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
```

Also can someone tell me where exactly do i need to put that `setNeedsDisplay()`?? do i need to have it in my view controller? my override drawract? thanks. Tell me if you need anything. I want it to draw the line in my view. like painting does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed my function `move` to this and worked:

```
func move(gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let state = gesture.state
        switch state
        {
        case .Ended:
            fallthrough
        case .Changed:
            gesture.setTranslation(gesture.locationInView(self), inView: self)
           p = gesture.translationInView(self)
            setNeedsDisplay()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

where `p` is a `CGPoint` variable and this helped me to move a rect on my `UIView`!Never Forget that `setNeedsDisplay()`!

Answer (score 0):

`setNeedsDisplay()` notifies your UIView that it needs to be redrawn within the next drawing cycle. In the `drawRect` function, you specify what should be drawn on the UIView. You want to change the appearance of your UIView everytime you have the Changed state in your GestureRecognizer, so that's also where you need to notify your view to be redrawn, i.e. call `setNeedsDisplay()`, and only there.

**Edit**

Here is the class you are searching for I believe

```
class theView: UIView
{
    var kl = 1
    var px : CGFloat = 0.0
    var py : CGFloat = 0.0
    var pxStart : CGFloat = 0.0
    var pyStart : CGFloat = 0.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "move:")
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: pxStart, y: pyStart))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: pxStart+px, y: pyStart+py))
        UIColor.blueColor().set()
        path.stroke()
    }

    func move(gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let state = gesture.state
        switch state
        {
        case .Began:
            pxStart = gesture.locationInView(self).x
            pyStart = gesture.locationInView(self).y
        case .Ended: fallthrough
        case .Changed:
            let translation = gesture.translationInView(self)
            px = translation.x
            py = translation.y
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but how can i also get this little animated feature of the line drawn in my view?

Comment: What do you mean by animated feature?

Comment: i mean that every time a new coordinate is being displayed via the pan gesture i want a line to be drawn from the last coordinate to the newest

Comment: not exactly what i want plus the self.setNeedsDisplay() in your override drawRect won't work

Comment: the setNeedsDisplay in the drawRect was an accident, shouldn't be there.