# Draw with UIPanGesture Swift

Tags: ios, swift4, uipangesturerecognizer

I try to draw with my app and everything worked with touches began/moved/ended, but I want to use UIPanGesture instead so I tried a few things, but I have no idea, how to make I work, because It didn't work an I had a few issues.

```
@objc func Drawing(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var lastpointo = CGPoint()
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began{
        lastpointo = recognizer.location(in: Drawinglayer)
    }else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended{
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastpointo, toPoint: lastpointo)
    }else{
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastpointo, toPoint: recognizer.translation(in: Drawinglayer))
        lastpointo = recognizer.location(in: Drawinglayer)
    }
}
```

This is the code for the Gesture function and the Code for drawLines is:

```
func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint){
    if DrawingActive == true{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        Drawinglayer.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Drawinglayer.frame.width, height: Drawinglayer.frame.height))

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

        context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
        context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(fontSizeOfDraw)
        context?.setStrokeColor(DrawingColor.cgColor)

        context?.strokePath()

        Drawinglayer.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        PickSize.isEnabled = false
        PickSize.alpha = 0
        ColorPickerController.isEnabled = false
        ColorPickerController.alpha = 0
        DrawBtn.isEnabled = false
        DrawBtn.alpha = 0
        SelectButton.isEnabled = false
        SelectButton.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

I hope someone could help me and give me good advice.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a good summary of your problem... can you clarify your question?

Comment: I try to draw like in Snapchat or instagram or so on, but it doesn’t really draw. It generates a few lines and you can draw with them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720450/trying-to-draw-on-a-uiview-with-uipangesture

Comment: I don't understand the code you said it is a duplicate of...