# Switch UITouch management from touchesBegan to UIScrollViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am developing an iOS drawing application where the main feature is that a user can load an image as background and then he can start finger drawing on top of it, zooming and panning the image with the draws on top of the image itself.

The schema of the application is the following one.

MainUiView->UIScrollView->UIImageView

Fingers drawing and tracking is managed on the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` override of the `UIResponder`.

The Zoom and Panning of the `UIImageView` is managed by the `UIScrollViewDelegate` implementation.

I have a button that switches the app mode from Drawing to Zooming and Panning mode in the following way:

**if you want to draw:**

```
    [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

so the touches are managed in the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` methods.

**if you want to Pan and Zoom with two fingers using the Pinch to Zoom gesture**

```
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

so the two fingers gesture is managed by the `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Now I am trying to evolve the app removing the button to switch from draw to zoom and pan mode.

My idea was to track the two fingers presence in the `touchesBegan` and then to disable the user interaction in the `UIImageView` to enable the user interaction in the scrollview, but the problem is that after doing this the touches are still managed in the `touchesMoved` method, nothing comes to the `scrollViewDelegate` until I lift my fingers from screen, after that, if I punt fingers again on the screen everything is managed by the `scrollViewDelegate`.

So to sum up: is it possible to stop the touches cycle after `touchesBegan` and propagate it to the `ScrollViewDelegate`?

If this is not possible, how can I achieve the zoom, panning and drawing feature on a `UImageView`? Should I remove the scrollview and try to zoom and pan the `UImageView` through the `UIResponder` methods ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Seeing the code you posted, it looks like you are using objc and not swift, am I right?

Comment: In the app I am using c# because the app is made in Xamarin.iOS but you are right the code I posted is objc. I am going to update the tag adding objc ..I really don't mind about the code used I can deal with both.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your implementation to use gesture recognisers instead of touch handling using the UIResponder methods.
Main benefits of this approach are :

- You can [use UIPanGestureRecognizer for drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720450/trying-to-draw-on-a-uiview-with-uipangesture), or even create a
  [custom recogniser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer)
- You can have dependency relationships between recognisers, using
  [requireGestureRecognizerToFail](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-requiregesturerecognizertofail), even across views
- You can loop through all recognisers on a view and disable only specific set of gestures without disabling touches on the entire view
- Gesture recognisers have the same touch related methods, which you can use to move your touch handling code from current implementation over to the gestures

So, your image view will have either pan or your custom gesture recogniser, with single touch, for drawing, and you can loop through scrollview's recognisers, and mark them not trigger if 'draw' gesture is triggered, using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`.

With this, you do not need to enable/disable user interaction on any of the views, although you will have to do a it of trial-and-error to get all gestures to work with each other correctly.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks Swapni so you are suggesting to move away from the ```UIResponder``` methods for the ```UIPanGestureRecognizer```. I read some posts about performance concern related to the ```UIPanGestureRecognizer``` for drawing are you aware of this ? Anyway thanks again..I will try your suggestion and  I'll notify my results here.